# My Character Sprite Doesn't Move Off Screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have been going over Paul Craven's Python and Pygame tutorial and lately I am trying to understand everything in Sprites. So, being inspired by Craven's multiple levels code, I've written my own code on it and it worked fine.

The logic is, if player sprite is off screen(for example screen width is equal to 640 and player's x value is greater than 640, than you are in the next level). Than, I decided to add menu to my game(?) and menu works fine as well.

The problem is, now my character can't get to second level. It seems it's x value is unable to pass 640, and I don't know why.

Since I am not able to use Stackoverflow editor good enough to share Python code(you know, intended), I will be using Pastebin to share my code.

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/10392389/

Stackoverflow doesn't let me post the image files I've used, but they are classic pictures I got from the internet.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if current_level_num == 1 and player.rect.x > SCREEN_WIDTH:
    current_level_num = 2
    current_level = levels[current_level_num]
    player.rect.x = 0

if current_level_num == 2 and player.rect.x < 1:
    current_level_num = 1
    current_level = levels[current_level_num]
    player.rect.x = SCREEN_WIDTH
```

The character moves to the 2nd level, then immediately moves back to the 1st. The player should be moved farther to the right than the level 2 boundary.

Comment: Thanks for your response but it didn't work. Actually, it was working before I've added the menu. I've printed my player's position to see what happens when it gets off screen, and the thing is it doesn't get off screen. It stucks in 640, it doesn't get 641.

Comment: Well, this is only other place that player.rect.x is set. Judging from this section of code, if the player's position reaches 641, it'll get set to 0 in the first section, then set to 640 in the second section. If you changed this section, please include the re-done version.

Comment: Oh my god, yes you are right. It seems I misunderstood your comment. Thank you.